# What is the meaning of this C code? [short-circuit evaluation]

Tags: c, logical-operators, short-circuiting

Jeffrey Stedfast offered [several functions that calculates the nearest power of 2](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2008/06/calculating-nearest-power-of-2.html). One of the functions has code as follows:

```c
static uint32_t
nearest_pow (uint32_t num)
{
  uint32_t j, k;
  (j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num); // What is this?
  ...
}
```

To fully understand the code, I tried changing the line to:

```
  j = num & 0xFFFF0000;
  j = j | (j = num);
```

Accidentally, I got a correct result. However, when I applied such transformation to the next lines (not included in my quotation), I got a wrong result. It turned out that I misunderstood the meaning of the code.

What is the meaning of `(j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);`?

Actually, I need to convert the function to other programming languages.

Comment: I will probably save you some time and efforts if ask you: "do you really need to port *this* concrete implementation with bit hacks in your language"? Maybe your language has a library function for that? Also, the difference between v2 and v4 is not that big, but v4 has some limitations. Will you benefit anything from it? This is not an answer for your question, but dropping this implementation entirely could be an indirect solution for [The problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Drop: In my opinion, functions that performs basic functionality should be implemented using the fastest possible approach. The need to use basic functions inside a loop of million times is likely to be encountered in our days. Yes, Indeed the last variant has limitations, but the limitations are potentially desirable in particular circumstances. Therefore, I will implement it as a variant to [Sean Eron Anderson's method](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is the logical or -operator. It has a short-circuiting behaviour such that if the left side is true, the right side is not evaluated (because the result of the logical or is known to be true already from the true left side).

In this case it is used in a roundabout way to provide a fallback assignment `j = num` if the first assignment `j = num & 0xFFFF0000` is zero (“false”). So, first the upper two bytes (mask `0xFFFF0000`) of `num` are assigned to `j`. If this is zero (“false”), i.e., the upper two bytes didn't have any 1-bits, then `num` is assigned to `j`.

Effectively this means “assign to `j` the upper two bytes of `num` if they are non-zero, otherwise assign to `j` the lower two bytes of `num`”.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know there is the _short-circuit evaluation_ in C before, and thank you for the explanation about the details of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
(j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);
```

Due to short-circuit evaluation of logical-OR operator, if `j = num & 0xFFFF0000` is non-0 (TRUE), then `j = num` won't be evaluated; otherwise, `j = num` will be evaluated afterwards.

Thus, the whole semantic is:

```
j = num & 0xFFFF0000;
if (j != 0) { // no operation
} else {
    j = num;
}
```

Comment: The no operation part is wrong. Think about it, what if num is 0x10000, then your expansion will have j = 0 whereas the original code would have j = 0x10000

Comment: @Arkku: Ah. OK. I missed it because in my own mind the semantics does not have an `else` condition, instead I think of the semantics of `||` to be `if (!j) ..`

Comment: @timrau: Actually all answer here deserves to accept but I have to chose only one answer. So, +1.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of (j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);?

Something of the form `a || b` will evaluate `a` and then evaluate `b` only if `a` was false. In other words, `j = num`, will be evaluated only if `j = num & 0xFFFF0000` is false. An expression is considered false in C++ if it is equal to 0, so this is equivalent to:

```
if ((j = num & 0xFFFF0000) == 0) {
    j = num;
}
```

Or, broken apart more might make it even clearer:

```
uint32_t masked = num & 0xFFFF0000;
if (masked == 0) {
    j = num;
} else {
    j = masked;
}
```

Comment: Actually all answer here deserves to accept but I have to chose only one answer. So, +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
(j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);
```

and,

```
j = num & 0xFFFF0000;
j = j | (j = num);
```

are not equivalent, I'm not sure why you get same result.

> What is the meaning of (j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);?

Before discussing what it exactly means you have to know the evaluation order of [logical *or*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68fx2f1.aspx) `||` operation, which is left to right. In C zero `0` means boolean `false` and any other non zero value means boolean `true`. Now look at the following expression,

```
left || right
```

If `left` is `true` then `right` will never be executed, `right` will only executed if and only if `left` is false.

Question remains, in which case `left` will be false? In this expression:

```
(j = num & 0xFFFF0000) || (j = num);
```

`(j = num & 0xFFFF0000)` will be false if `j` is assigned with `0` means `num & 0xFFFF0000` produce `0`.

So if `num & 0xFFFF0000` produce `0` then the right expression will executed `(j = num)` and `j` finally updated by `num`. End of story.

> Now what the following code means?

```
j = j | (j = num);
```

it means, assign `num` into `j` and perform [bitwise *or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_.22.7C.22) `|` with previous `j` and reassign the final value into `j`.

Comment: @rakeb_void: +1. Actually your answer also deserves to accept but I have to chose only one answer.